# IBOutlet didn't work with Hard Code constraints

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout, flkautolayout

I have new issue related to Auto-Layout world , i can summarize the problem in the below steps:

1- I have storyboard with only one scene contain UIImageView .

2- I went to viewcontroller.m file and add manual constraints like below code

```
[self.bgImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


NSLayoutConstraint *horizentalSpaceConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bgImageView
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                            toItem:self.view
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                                          constant:0.0]; 
[self.view addConstraint:horizentalSpaceConstraint];
```

**Result :**

The constraint didn't affect the IBoutlet for UIImageView but if i add UIImageView from hard coded in viewcontroller.m file it works ,can you help me to discover this problem.

Comment: Did you ever add that constraint to self.view?

Comment: Yes , I have added it like above code

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which can describe by ( Every constraints used IBOutlet elements should before begin add only the below line **without** need to [setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints :No]

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    // Step 1 remove view constraints for IBOutlet elements  

    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
}
```